# kendo Grid column with angular bootstrap popover using a template for dynamic list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, kendo-grid, popover, bootstrap-popover

I am trying to show the list of item names in a popover when hovering on a column of count with Kendo Grid.
The item names are got back from an API response.

I am using popover-template to reference the external template. For some reason , my external template i snot being referenced when i use popover-template. When i use static data with just popover its fine. but in my case i need to build a list based on teh number of items

```
     columns: [
            {  field: 'name',
                title: 'APP',
                template: function (a) {
                    var tmp = '<a ng-href="#/applications/'+a.id+'">'+a.name+'</a>';
                    return tmp;
                }
            },
            {  field: 'count',
                title: 'COUNT',
                template: function(dataItem) {
                    var htmlTemplate = $templateCache.get('appCount.html');
                    $scope.applications = dataItem.applications;
                    var htmlObj = $compile(htmlTemplate)($scope);

                    var tmp ='<span popover-template="'+htmlObj.html()+'" popover-placement="right" popover-trigger="mouseenter" data-html="true">'+dataItem.count+'</span>';
                    return tmp;

                }

            }
    ]
```

The external template is saved as appCount.html and has the following

```
      <ul class="app-popover">
      <li ng-repeat="app in applications" ng-bind-html="app.name">
      </li>
     </ul>
```

I basically am trying to bind the dynamic data to $scope variable  for referencing within the controller that it is called from.

Is there any other way to build this list  and show a tooltip . any help is appreciated. I am struggling with this and also new to angular